# How to prove this set has infinite measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(a_k)$ be a sequence of real numbers and $A=\{a_k:k \in \mathbb{N}\}$.
Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ , $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty $ $\frac{1}{4^k|x-a_k|}$ , if x $\notin A$ and $f(x)= \infty$ , if x $\in A$.
How can I prove that $m(\{x \in \mathbb{R} :f(x)<1\})= \infty$ , where m is the Lebesgue measure ?

The first thing that I tried doing is assuming the sequence of functions $f_k(x)=$ $\frac{1}{4^k|x-a_k|}$ and find that $\int f_k dm= \infty $

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $U_k=\left\{x:\left|x-a_k\right|\leq 2^{-k}\right\}$ and $U=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty U_k$. Then $m\left(U\right) \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty m\left(U_k\right)=2$ since $m\left(U_k\right)=2^{-k+1}$.

If $V=\mathbb R-U$ then $m\left(V\right)=\infty$. For each $x\in V$ we have $|x-a_k|>2^{-k}$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$ so that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{4^k|x-a_k|} < \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{4^k \cdot 2^{-k}} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k}=1
$$
that means $f\left(x\right)<1$. Then $V\subset X=\left\{x \in \mathbb{R} :f(x)<1\right\}$ and $m\left(X\right)\geq m\left(V\right)=\infty$.

This proves $m(\{x \in \mathbb{R} :f(x)<1\})=m(X)= \infty$.